# Time out exception in 1st run for local DB

Tags: .net-3.5, connection-string, sql-server-express, datadirectory

My connection string is like the following.  It shows 'Timeout Exception' first time I run the application.  But, for the subsequent run, it's ok.  I think, it might take some time to attach the DB to the SQLExpress Server.  Is there anyway to increase Timeout period?  Thanks

I am using SQLServer 2005 Express and VS 2008 and .Net 3.5.

```
<add name="dotnetConnectionString" connectionString="Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|dotnet.mdf; Database=dotnet;Trusted_Connection=Yes;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: Is this attaching of a database something you should be doing in your application's setup? Or do you need to attach the database every time your app runs? Seems like a lot of hard work for an app to cope with every time it starts up!

Comment: This is not for production.  I am just doing school project and, when I tried to run my project in another PC for the 1st time, this problem occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Connection Timeout in your connection string and specify the number of seconds.  Try 60 at first.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal on slower machines. In my local db, I run a batch file before using the database, with the following command:

@"\SqlLocalDB.exe" create  -s

example:
@"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\SqlLocalDB.exe" create v11.0 -s

Answer (score 0):

https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012/

Read this part:
'The first connection to LocalDB will create and start the instance, this takes some time and might cause a connection timeout failure. If this happens, wait a bit and connect again.'

Comment: Link only answers are nor considered as good answers, please consider adding more to your answer...